# How does Tor Browser deal with cookies? I never see them in Tor

Tags: cookies

I'm using Tor Browser with Tor Network disabled. I usually keep Accept Cookies unchecked, but some sites, like the bank and email, require cookies, so I have to enable them. However, I never see them in my browser after clicking Show Cookies. I've even tried it while still logged in the previously mentioned sites, and I still don't see the cookies.

What would cause them to not show up in the list?

Answer (score 1):

Tor Browser borrows a lot of Firefox's private browsing functionality in order to implement its advanced security features.

In Firefox's private browsing mode, cookies are accepted but will not show up in that graphical dialog.

As a side effect, while Tor Browser will accept cookies by default, they will not show up in that dialog.